# How to format int number to decimal/double amount

Tags: c#, .net

So im receiving amounts as int's from an API im using like this: **1000** and **1235** which in its real amount is **10.00** and **12.35**

So i want to convert the int numbers to their decimal form, how would i do that in c#?

Example:
`850 > 8.50` `8500 > 85.00` `90002 > 900.02` `136789 > 1367.89`

Comment: How about `i / 100M` to get the `decimal` type or just `i / 100.0` to get the `double` type?

Comment: How about: `value / 100.0`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on the type of result you want, either `float`, `double` or `decimal`, the following 3 similar expressions can be used:

```
int i = 1235;
float f = i / 100f;    // equivalent to float f = 12.35f;
double d1 = i / 100d;  // equivalent to double d1 = 12.35d;
decimal d2 = i / 100m; // equivalent to decimal d2 = 12.35m;
```

Note that `12.35` is not accurately representable by `float` or `double`, so you'll actually have a "close enough" value, either something like 12.3499999999999999 or 12.3500000000000001. If this is monetary or countables, I would suggest using `decimal`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int apiNum = 8500;
double myNum = Convert.ToDouble(apiNum) / 100;

// Output 85
Console.WriteLine(myNum);

// If you really need those .00 Output 85.00
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:0.00}", myNum));
```